# Array declaration in C# from a Service Class

Tags: c#

I have a array type something like this

ZData and this array has a field called "field1"

I am trying to declare something like

```
ZData data1= new Zdata[]{}
data1[0].field1="12345"

The above code throws me a index out of bounds exception error but it builds successfully
```

This is a predefined array with only one field and I have to pass this array to an method

```
 [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ZData", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/csservice.data")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class ZData : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    private string Field1Field;

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
        get {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
    public string Field1 {
        get {
            return this.Field1Field;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.Field1Field, value) != true)) {
                this.Field1Field = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Field1Field");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZData data1 = new Zdata[]{}` declares an *empty* array - there are no elements.

So, `data1[0]`, referring to the first element, is out of bounds.

Instead, declare the length of your array:

```
ZData data1 = new ZData[1];     // length 1
```

Note that, unless `ZData` is a `struct`, you *also* have to instantiate every array entry before using it:

```
data1[0] = new ZData();
data1[0].field1 = "12345";
```

Alternatively, use a `List<T>` instead of an array, and you won't have to declare the length up front:

```
List<ZData> data1 = new List<ZData>();
data1.Add(new ZData() { field1 = "12345" });
```